# Compute correlation matrices of dataset list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, correlation

I have a list of `pandas` datasets like the one below:

```
dataset_list=[df1,df2,df3]
```

What I need to do is compute the correlation coefficient of each dataset. Since I would not like to do this manually, I tried to use a for loop to accomplish this:

```
for dataset in dataset_list:
    corr_matrices=dataset.corr()
    corr_matrices.to_csv(str(dataset)+'Correlation_Matrices.csv', sep=',')
```

However, the output only shows the correlation matrix for the last dataset and not the first two. How can I fix this and save each correlation matrix in its own separate .csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store each output. Here `corr_matrices` is just a variable inside the loop.
Try this one

```
dataset_list=[df1,df2,df3]

output_list = list()
for i,dataset in enumerate(dataset_list):
    corr_matrices=dataset.corr()
    output_list.append(corr_matrices)
    dataset.to_csv(str(i)+'_Correlation_Matrices.csv', sep=",")

for i in output_list:
    display(i)
```

Comment: Nice that works in creating the matrices. However, how would you go about saving them to different files? I tried <for i in output_list:
    i.to_csv(f"{pathfolder}/{dataset.replace(' ', '_')}_Correlation_Matrix.csv", index=True, sep=",")> but it returns an error

Comment: try the updated code. you cant use the `str(df)` . this will give you a large string. if this works, accept it as a main answer